# Declaring dynamical variables Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

My question is the next.
I wanna make this:

```
<?
 $item1='';
 $item2='';
 //etc..
?>
```

but like this:

```
    foreach ($cart as $item) {
                foreach ($item as $key => $value) {
//so if foreach current is 3 to be $item3=new Item(); etc..
                    $item1 = new Item();
                    $item1->setName('Ground Coffee 40 oz')
                      ->setCurrency('USD')
                      ->setQuantity(1)
                      ->setSku("123123") // Similar to `item_number` in Classic API
                      ->setPrice(7.5);
                }
            }
```

So I hope,are you going to understand what I want.
Thanks

Comment: You mean you want to create new variables named item with $key as number?

Comment: Please reword it, I have literally no idea what you are asking for.

Comment: Why do you want to do this instead of having the values in an array?

Comment: OP you should read my update on my answer. I noticed you accepted my answer while I was typing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a variable dynamically with variable variables.
http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php

If I understood your question and code correct this should be the way to do it:

```
foreach ($cart as $item) {
            foreach ($item as $key => $value) {
//so if foreach current is 3 to be $item3=new Item(); etc..
                ${"item" . $key} = new Item();
                ${"item" . $key}->setName('Ground Coffee 40 oz')
                  ->setCurrency('USD')
                  ->setQuantity(1)
                  ->setSku("123123") // Similar to `item_number` in Classic API
                  ->setPrice(7.5);
            }
        }
```

See here an example: https://3v4l.org/VUHXS

---

It's not a good way to solve the problem in my opinion.
You should probably use an array instead.

The problem with creating new variables like this is that you don't know where it ends.
Is there one item or 50?
It's not the end of the world, you can manage with something like:

```
While(isset(${"item" . $i})){
    Echo ${"item" . $i};
    $i++;
}
```

It will work as good as a for or foreach but it will be harder to debug.
With an array you can just var_dump it and see the contents.
It's slightly harder with individual variables.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

```
$itemArray=[];
foreach ($cart as $item) {
    foreach ($item as $key => $value) {
//so if foreach current is 3 to be $item3=new Item(); etc..
        $item1 = new Item();
        $item1->setName('Ground Coffee 40 oz')
            ->setCurrency('USD')
            ->setQuantity(1)
            ->setSku("123123") // Similar to `item_number` in Classic API
            ->setPrice(7.5);
        $itemArray[]=$item1;
    }
}
```